# How do I use vscode's default html formatter in vim?

Tags: html, unix, visual-studio-code, vim

So in vscode I use the default html formatter given by `vscode.html-language-features`

And now I want to use the same formatter but in vim.
How would I go about doing this?
I currently have vim-autoformat as a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

So to work around this, I just used vim-prettier and made a custom configuration file inside my .vimrc.